# If I install a leaked ROM on my device will I be able to receive OTA updates?

Tags: rom-flashing, ota-update

Specifically, I'm interested in flashing a leaked build of Ice Cream Sandwich on my Nexus S 4G. I'd like to get in on the action early, but this is something I'd like to know.

Answer (score 5):

If you are installing a custom ROM that is not a "carrier leak" then you probably will no longer receive OTA notifications/updates.

In the custom ROMs they remove the OTA settings that the carriers use. I don't know exactly what is changed/removed, but I can't even tell you the last time I have had an OTA notification.

But if you use tools like [ClockWorkMod Rom Manager](http://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager/) you can get notifications for updates to the ROM you install if it is added to Rom Manager by the developers. This is how I get my update notifications for [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/).